# Nuxt 3 set cookies on FE

Tags: cookies, nuxtjs3

I'm migrating a project to Nuxt 3 and I don't know how to convert a Nuxt 2 code using the new `setup` script

I have a login that if return a 200 response I would save 2 cookie but

```
$fetch(`${runtimeConfig.public.BASE_API_BROWSER_URL}/user/login`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value,
  }
})
.then((resp) => {
  localStorage.setItem('Bearer', resp.access_token)

  // Cookie.set('Bearer', resp.data.access_token, { expires: 7 })

  isSubmitting.value = false
  window.location.href = '/profile/'
})
```

I was using `js-cookie` but I was wondering if I could achieve the same without the need of a dependency, I know I can use vanilla js but I was wondering if [use-cookie](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie) would work as well.

I've tried this `useCookie('Bearer', resp.access_token, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 })` but doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leveraging the built in `useCookie` would look like this to set a value:

```js
// Login Script
const myCookieToken = useCookie('myCookieToken', { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 })

$fetch('...').then(response => {
  myCookieToken.value = response.access_token
}
```

To retrieve the value later in another script or component:

```js
const myCookieToken = useCookie('myCookieToken')

console.log(myCookieToken.value)
```

PS... You may want to use `navigateTo('/profile')` instead of `window.location.href` so you get the nice built in page transition.

Comment: thank you so much :) I was trying something similar but wasn't working. Now everything is working and thanks about the tips about `navigateTo()`